# How to work @Inheritance plus GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to create a way to model my future aplications using an AbstractEntity
My problem now is the Sequence type for Postgres

In my abstract class I don't now how generate one sequence per entity class

It is possible?

**Abstract**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Abstract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seq_Broker",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_Broker",sequenceName="seq_Broker")
    private Long id;

}
```

**EntityModel**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_EntityModel")
public class EntityModel extends Abstract{

    private String value;
    private String value2;

    public EntityModel(String value, String value2) {
        this.value = value;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, your Abstract class should be annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`, and not with `@Entity` nor `Inheritance`. I would simply put the id field in the subclass. You can put abstract getters/setters in the base class though.

Comment: @JBNizet but if I do that how I reuse the `hashCode` and `equals` method? I want create a generic converter too

Comment: You'd better not put those methods in the base class anyway. Usually, everything works finer without these methods. If you really need to compare detached entities using equals(), you shouldn't use the autogenerated ID to compare them. And anyway, even if you really want to use the ID, you just need to call getId() in hashCode() and equals().

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with an `@Entity` superclass for any inheritance types, as the master table (the table for `Abstract`) will always contain the used ids - and it is obvious that you can only use one sequence for that, as otherwise you would have a problem with uniqueness.

But you can define `@MappedSuperclass` for `Abstract`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Abstract {
    public static final String SEQUENCE_GENERATOR = "seq";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE_GENERATOR)
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_EntityModel")
@SequenceGenerator(name = Abstract.SEQUENCE_GENERATOR, sequenceName = "tb_entity_sequence")
public class EntityModel extends Abstract { 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: I use that form but I keep the `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` and works fine for me. Thanks

Comment: `@Inheritance` is ignored if you don't use it for anything else than an `@Entity` - so it makes no sense to keep it anyway.